# Django: how can i get a model that store a list(like in python or anyway) of a sizes of a shoes

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

excuse my English
I'm beginner in django and i want to achieve this in my model and form:

the scenario is like purchasing shoes on amazon:
1. the shoes has list of size a user can select form 
2. the user select and add it to the cart 
3. user place an order which is saved in a model with the respective size included

now imagine a shoe seller when selling can enter a list of sizes like this in python size = [1, 2, 3, 4] which is also saved on a shoe-model

how can implement this in django and how to save a list of size entered but a seller to  a model and how can i display this list so the user can select only one of the value of this list?

please help

Comment: Please Take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to let sellers specify which sizes their items are offered in, and then let users pick one of those sizes. And the sizes need to follow a certain pattern, e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4, ... 11, 12]. Is that right?

The [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices) option would let you select *one* size for each object, but if you want to let each object have more than one size, it wouldn't be enough.

This sounds like a candidate for a [many-to-many relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) between a Product table and a Size table. In the Size table, you can create an entry for each shoe size that your store will offer, like size 6, size 7, and so on:

```
class Size(models.Model):
    foot_size = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(choices=(('F', 'Female'), ('M', 'Male'), ('U', 'Ungendered')))

# Sample to create a size
s1 = Size(foot_size=6, gender='F')
s1.save()
s2 = Size(foot_size=7, gender='F')
s2.save()
```

Then, in the Product model, add a field for Size, e.g.

```
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size, help_text="Sizes of the product that are offered.")
```

You can then create a new product as follows:

```
sizes = Size.objects.filter(foot_size__in=[6, 7], gender='F')
p = Product(sizes=sizes)
p.save()
```

The product `p` will then be tied to two female foot sizes: 6 and 7. This way, when a seller is creating a product, they can specify which sizes are on offer - and in your forms, this will automatically populate with all the Size objects in your database. Then, when a customer is buying a product, they would specify one of the sizes on offer for that product.

You could expand the Size model or the Product model as necessary to accommodate more products, but probably simpler is easier. Hope this gets you started, and see the link to the Django documentation on many-to-many relations for more ways you could use it.

Comment: class Size(models.Model): 
         size1 = models.PositiveInteger()
         size2 = models.PositiveInteger()
    class Product(models.Model):
         sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size)

like this above?:
so in this class we have defined two entry for the size image if the seller has 3 or more ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the list to json and store it in a charfield.